# Easy verification of sum of quadratic forms optimized over unit sphere

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose I want to optimize the following

$$\sup_{\|u\|_2\le 1}\sum_{i}^Ku_i x^TP_ix$$

where $x$ is a fixed vector and $P_i$ are positive semidefinite matrices. Apparently this supremum should be equal

$$ (\sum_{i}^K (x^TP_ix)^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

how can we prove this?

I tried to bound one of the parts $$u_i x^TP_ix \le |u_i|\|x\|^2_2\|P_ix\|^2_2 $$ and thought we might take $u_i=\frac{x^TP_ix}{\|x^TP_ix\|}$ but doesn't lead (as far as I see) to the right solution.